# FacetWP was unable to auto-detect the post listing : Having an issue with ACF load choices causing FacetWP error

Tags: filters

I have a project website in which I am using Facewp to list custom posts on which I attached a custom field using ACF. I am using Extended ACF to make frontend forms to create/update those post types. The issue I am having is that the filters I used on the archive page for those posts are not working when I put the Acf/load-field('custom-field) on theme function.php to dynamically populate the choices on the ACF frontend form. The FW filters show: **FacetWP was unable to auto-detect the post listing**.

I added facewp=>true on facewp queries. I am thinking that a solution to get these two to work without interfering would be to keep acf/load_field functions off the pages where the FacetWP filters are used but I cannot figure that out since acf/load_field seems to only work when loaded only in function.php which immediately affect the FacetWP filters.
Can anyone give an idea?

the following is the ACF/load_field :

````
function acf_admin_enqueue( $hook ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'populate-awards', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/populate_grant_programs.js' );
   
    wp_localize_script( 'populate-awards', 'pa_vars', array(
          'pa_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'pa_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
        )
    );
  }
//add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'acf_admin_enqueue' );
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acf_admin_enqueue');

  // Return awards by grant project
function awards_by_grant_project( $selected_grant_project ) {
    // Verify nonce
    if( !isset( $_POST['pa_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pa_nonce'], 'pa_nonce' ) ){
        die('Permission denied');
    }
    // Get grant project var
    $selected_grant_project = $_POST['grant_project'];
    // Get field from options page
    $org_post_id = get_post_id_for_organization();
    $projects = organizations_grant_projects();
    $grant_projects_listerr = $projects[ $org_post_id ];
    //var_dump($grant_projects_listerr); die();
    $grantproject_data = [];
    foreach( $grant_projects_listerr as $grant_project ){
        if( $grant_project[ 'project_title' ] == $selected_grant_project ){
            $grantproject_data[ 'awards' ] = [ $grant_project[ 'award_number' ] ];
            $grantproject_data[ 'grant_programs' ] = $grant_project[ 'grant_programs' ];
        }
    }
    return wp_send_json($grantproject_data);
    die();
  }
   
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_awards_by_grant_project', 'awards_by_grant_project' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_awards_by_grant_project', 'awards_by_grant_project' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_awards_by_grant_project', 'awards_by_grant_project' );```
````

The query for organization:

```
 function organizations_grant_projects(){
    $array_obj_of_orgs = array();
    $args = [
        'post_type' =>  'organizations',
        'meta_key'  => 'grant_projects_for_directory',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'post_title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ];
    $org_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $org_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $org_query->have_posts() ): $org_query->the_post();
            if( have_rows('grant_projects_for_directory') ):
                while( have_rows('grant_projects_for_directory' ) ) : the_row();
                    $array_of_grant_project[] = ['project_title' => get_sub_field('project_title'), 'award_number' => get_sub_field('list_of_award_numbers')[0] ['award_number'] ?? '', 'grant_programs' => get_sub_field('grant_programs')?? ''];
                endwhile;
            endif;
            $array_obj_of_orgs[get_the_ID()] = $array_of_grant_project;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $array_obj_of_orgs;
 }
```

Here is the link to the website filter pages: [faceWp filter directory page](https://ldev.ta2ta.org/directory/) 
and [facewp filter library page](https://ldev.ta2ta.org/document-library/).

if anyone would be willing to take a look I can share the admin access.

Comment: You should really be asking FacetWP and ACF these questions as their code is proprietary and they're third parties which means their plugins don't necessarily work the same way WP does.  WPSE is for WordPress specific development questions - these plugins have paid tiers and they provide support for stuff like this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank you for taking a look at my issue if you did. I was able to get the issue resolved thanks to FaceWp support team. What I realized is that when you are usind facetwp plugin, and you are having an issue with filters not working when the refresh ajax is fired, just add a nonce to ajax, for some reason mine was failing.

Note that the main reason is for authentication described [here](https://facetwp.com/how-to-pass-authentication-data-through-rest-api-requests/). This resolved the issue I was having.

```
/*
 * Authentication for facet
 * Please note that caching may interfere with the NONCE,
 * causing AJAX requests to fail. Please DISABLE CACHING for facet pages,
 * or set the cache expiration to < 12 hours!
*/

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
  ?>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        if (! FWP.loaded) { // initial pageload
          FWP.hooks.addFilter('facetwp/ajax_settings', function(settings) {
            settings.headers = { 'X-WP-Nonce': FWP_JSON.nonce };
            return settings;
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}, 100 );
```